# Cordova keeps changing app name to 'Hello Cordova'

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I have a cordova app for android that works fine, it compiles without any issues and I can also create an APK without any problems. However, whenever the app is installed on a device it's name show's up as 'Hello Cordova'

I've changed the `<name>` property in `config.xml` in the app's root directory to reflect the correct name but this does not seem to have any effect as everytime the app compiles `config.xml` in `/platforms/android/res/xml/` overwrites the `<name>` property with Hello Cordova.

I've also tried to edit /platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml to reflect the correct name but that does not work either

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Hello Cordova</string>
    </resources>`
```

How can I fix this so that I can set the name of the app so that when it is installed on a device it displays correctly?

Comment: I had the same problem and found that building it again worked. I am using `npm cca`. After `cca build android`, which seems to be a wrapper for `cordova build android`, the .apk file loaded as "Hello Cordova". But I repeated the build and it always works correctly on the 2nd attempt.

Comment: I did it by editing android->res->values->strings.xml. In strings.xml edit <string name="app_name">*Your APP Name*</string>

Answer (score 2):

changing the `<name>` parameter in `/platforms/android/cordova/defaults.xml`
to the correct value has fixed the problem

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0">
    <name>My App</name>
```